# Button link doesn't work on android web browser

Tags: android, html, button

I use chrome browser, firefox browser on android os,This is mysite `http://edtech.edu.chula.ac.th/research/innovation/App/GameQuestion/question.html`
I just want to know How to fix this please.thank you for your reply.

Comment: Are you trying to go to that url from your app on button click ?

Comment: No."http://edtech.edu.chula.ac.th/research/innovation/App/GameQuestion/question.html " I want to make button link in question.html and go to another website but The archor link or button link doesn't work on chrome browser, firefox browser on android os.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a div, not a button. Replace the div for the "button" with

```
<button id="Text_Entry_Button_4" class="cp-frameset" tabindex="2500" style="outline-style: none; z-index: 4; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039); display: block; left: 873px; top: 536px; width: 125px; height: 76px;"><div id="Text_Entry_Button_4accStr" style="opacity: 0; width: 0px; height: 0px; left: -1999px; position: fixed;"><p> </p></div></div>
```

Then you can use javascript or php to submit their answer.

Comment: https://mailkmuttacth-my.sharepoint.com/personal/tunlaton_ruronin_mail_kmutt_ac_th/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=1fc90f9b13f00406498984b1f91986dc0&authkey=Aea817lL_cpZ13ZHfuESe0U This is my code.I think Js can't not work with document.body.innerHTML.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this block of code work to you:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://edtech.edu.chula.ac.th/research/innovation/App/GameQuestion/question.html");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```